# Icecat & PHP files.index.xml

Tags: php, xml, e-commerce

I have several scripts running that downloads the daily xml and looks for every .xml in it and downloads them to a different folder so

```
                    1234.xml
                  / 
daily.index.xml - - 4567.xml
                  \
                    6789.xml
```

Now I wish to do the same with the files.index.xml file, But everytime I try to open the index file the server stops with:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 1073217536 bytes)

Is there a way to open up and dissect files.index.xml without my server to crash constantly?

Update:
I believe the server hangs somewhere while running the script, as some XML files are beeing stored in the directory

Script:

```
// URL for index file
$url = "http://data.icecat.biz/export/level4/EN/files.index.xml";


// Custom header (username/pass is a paid account, so I can't share the credentials)
$context = stream_context_create(array (
    'http' => array (
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("username:pass")
    )
));

// Get XML File
$indexfile = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


// Save XML
$file = '../myhomeservices/fullindex/files_index.xml';
unlink($file); 
$dailyfile = fopen("../myhomeservices/fullindex/files_index.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
chmod($dailyfile, 0777); 
// Write the contents back to the file
$dailyxmlfile = fwrite($dailyfile, $indexfile);
if($dailyxmlfile){
} else {
echo 'Error!';  
}
fclose($myfile);enter code here
```

Apache logs that 'file_get_contents($url, false, $context);' is leading to max out the memory.

Currently I'm trying to upload the files.index.xml (1,41gb file) in hope that I can process it this way.

Comment: you need to show the code that causes the error

Comment: Can you post the code that's accessing and parsing the XML files? The code is attempting to allocate 1GB of RAM on top of the 1GB you've already allowed it to use.

Comment: Also what's Icecat? Is that supposed to be Icecast, the streaming tool?

Comment: @Will based on the xml im thinking http://icecat.biz/

Comment: dont read the whole file in to memory do it in chunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided, there are two issues here. The most direct issue is that you're trying to allocate an extra 1GB of memory to your PHP script after it's already reached its 1GB limit (which is much higher than the default limit). Assuming you're using PHP 5.1+, you can use `fopen()` and `file_put_contents()` together to buffer the file between HTTP and disk:

```
<?php
$url = "http://data.icecat.biz/export/level4/EN/files.index.xml";

// Custom header (username/pass is a paid account, so I can't share the credentials)
$context = stream_context_create(array (
    'http' => array (
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("username:pass")
    )
));

$file = '../myhomeservices/fullindex/files_index.xml';
@unlink($file); 
chmod($file, 0777); 

// Write the contents back to the file
if (!file_put_contents($file, fopen($url, 'r', false, $context)))
{
    echo 'Error!';  
}
```

If you need more control over the buffering, you can `fread()` a fixed-size buffer from HTTP and `fwrite()` the buffer to the output file as you read it. You can also use the PHP cURL Extension to download the file, if you'd rather cURL handle the buffering.

As posted, your code reads the entire remote file into memory, then makes a copy of the whole thing as it writes it into the output file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `fopen()` for my example rather than `file_get_contents()`. But yes, `fopen()`/`fread()` would work fine, but then you have to worry about properly handling edge cases. `fgets()` reads line by line, and "chunks" would be more appropriate here.